# jquery validation of the form except one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, validation, jquery-selectors

I want to validate complete content of my form except all the inputs that are in a specific div, 
lets say `<div class="noValid">` for example.

So what I want to do is something like `$("myForm").valid()` that will execute jQuery validation on all the form inputs except the ones that are in my specific div.

Can you tell me how to exclude this specific div from the global form selector?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass a selector in the `ignore` option to `validate()`:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    // your options,
    ignore: ":hidden, #yourDiv :input"
});
```

From there on, `$("#myForm").valid()` will ignore the form controls inside `#yourDiv`.

Comment: how to add rule to elements which are not part of the form?